# How do I call variable in sql.open function of golang

Tags: go

How do I achieve replacing of the practice of calling actual password in above code with a variable.

```
pwd := "password"
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:pwd@/events")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error: Failed to connect events schema. \n")
    return
}
defer db.Close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the hardcoded string, use fmt.Sprintf:

```
pwd := "password"
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", fmt.Sprintf("root:%s@/events", pwd))
```

Docs:
https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf

Simple GoPlay:
https://play.golang.org/p/TKSvTuD8BY